# How do I create a namespace package in Python?

Tags: python, namespaces, package

In Python, a namespace package allows you to spread Python code among several projects. This is useful when you want to release related libraries as separate downloads. For example, with the directories `Package-1` and `Package-2` in `PYTHONPATH`,

```
Package-1/namespace/__init__.py
Package-1/namespace/module1/__init__.py
Package-2/namespace/__init__.py
Package-2/namespace/module2/__init__.py
```

the end-user can `import namespace.module1` and `import namespace.module2`.

What's the best way to define a namespace package so more than one Python product can define modules in that namespace?

Comment: It looks to me like module1 and module2 are actually subpackages rather than modules. As I understand it, a module is basically a single file. Maybe subpkg1 and subpkg2 would make more sense as names?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

TL;DR:

On Python 3.3 you don't have to do anything, just don't put any `__init__.py` in your namespace package directories and it will just work. On pre-3.3, choose the `pkgutil.extend_path()` solution over the `pkg_resources.declare_namespace()` one, because it's future-proof and already compatible with implicit namespace packages.

---

Python 3.3 introduces implicit namespace packages, see [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/).

This means there are now three types of object that can be created by an `import foo`:

- A module represented by a `foo.py` file
- A regular package, represented by a directory `foo` containing an `__init__.py` file
- A namespace package, represented by one or more directories `foo` without any `__init__.py` files

Packages are modules too, but here I mean "non-package module" when I say "module".

First it scans `sys.path` for a module or regular package. If it succeeds, it stops searching and creates and initalizes the module or package. If it found no module or regular package, but it found at least one directory, it creates and initializes a namespace package.

Modules and regular packages have `__file__` set to the `.py` file they were created from. Regular and namespace packages have `__path__`set to the directory or directories they were created from.

When you do `import foo.bar`, the above search happens first for `foo`, then if a package was found, the search for `bar` is done with `foo.__path__`as the search path instead of `sys.path`. If `foo.bar` is found, `foo` and `foo.bar` are created and initialized.

So how do regular packages and namespace packages mix? Normally they don't, but the old `pkgutil` explicit namespace package method has been extended to include implicit namespace packages.

If you have an existing regular package that has an `__init__.py` like this:

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

... the legacy behavior is to add any other *regular* packages on the searched path to its `__path__`. But in Python 3.3, it also adds namespace packages.

So you can have the following directory structure:

```
├── path1
│   └── package
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── foo.py
├── path2
│   └── package
│       └── bar.py
└── path3
    └── package
        ├── __init__.py
        └── baz.py
```

... and as long as the two `__init__.py` have the `extend_path` lines (and `path1`, `path2` and `path3` are in your `sys.path`) `import package.foo`, `import package.bar` and `import package.baz` will all work.

`pkg_resources.declare_namespace(__name__)` has not been updated to include implicit namespace packages.

Comment: What about setuptools? Do I have to use the `namespace_packages` option? And the [`__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#namespace-packages) thing?

Comment: Should I add `namespace_packages=['package']` in the `setup.py`?

Comment: @laurentlaport Good question! If you are on Python 3.3+, I hope not, but please experiment and come back with an answer. ;-) I looked at http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#namespace-packages , but it's not clear if this is legacy documentation that has not been updated, or if it's still valid.

Comment: @kawingchiu Please see my comment to `laurentlaport`. `declare_namespace` is obsolete, from what I understand, but the `namespace_packages` option needs investigation. (NOTE: I base this on what I have read. I have not released any packages using Setuptools.)

Comment: Yes to both kawing-chiu and laurentlaport. Tested on Python 3.4.4

Comment: @clacke: With `namespace_packages=['package']`, setup.py will add a ``namespace_packages.txt`` in the EGG-INFO. Still don't know the impacts…

Comment: Good to know, whatever it means. :-) Hope someone else (or you, when you figured it out) can fill in the details.

Comment: @kawing-chiu The benefit of `pkg_resources.declare_namespace` over `pkgutil.extend_path` is that it will continue to monitor `sys.path`. That way, if a new item is added to `sys.path` after a package in the namespace is first loaded then packages in the namespace in that new path item are still able to be loaded. (A benefit of using `__import__('pkg_resources')` over `import pkg_resources` is that you don't end up `pkg_resources` being exposed as `my_namespace_pkg.pkg_resources`.)

Comment: @ArthurTacca Interesting. How does it do that? It adds module resolution code to the package instead of just extending `__path__`?

Comment: @clacke It doesn't work that way (but it has the same effect as if it did). It maintains a global list of all package namespaces created with that function, and watches `sys.path`. When `sys.path` changes it checks if that affects the `__path__` of any namespace, and if it does then it updates those `__path__` properties.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure how it does it. The source code is here: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/7c0c39ef1f60571709e5a8e6680f2147c38cd4ff/pkg_resources/__init__.py

Answer (score 81):

There's a standard module, called [pkgutil](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html), with which you
can 'append' modules to a given namespace.

With the directory structure you've provided:

```
Package-1/namespace/__init__.py
Package-1/namespace/module1/__init__.py
Package-2/namespace/__init__.py
Package-2/namespace/module2/__init__.py
```

You should put those two lines in both `Package-1/namespace/__init__.py` and `Package-2/namespace/__init__.py` (*):

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

(* since -unless you state a dependency between them- you don't know which of them will be recognized first - see [PEP 420](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) for more information)

As the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html) says:

> This will add to the package's `__path__` all subdirectories of directories on `sys.path` named after the package.

From now on, you should be able to distribute those two packages independently.

Comment: What are the pros and cons of using that versus __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__) ?

Comment: First, `__import__` is considered bad style in this case as it can be easily replaced with plain import statement. 
More to the point, pkg_resources is a non-standard library. It comes with setuptools, so that's a non-issue, though. Quick googling reveals that pkgutil was introduced in 2.5 and pkg_resources predates it. Nevertheless, pkgutil is a oficially-recognized solution. pkg_resources inclusion was, in fact, rejected in PEP 365.

Comment: Their functionality is probably the same, though, as zope.interface uses both in it's `__init__.py`.

Comment: @MikeHordecki pkgutil was introduced in python 2.3 actually.

Comment: Rejection to be included as part of the standard library doesn't necessarily imply outright rejection of the idea as unsound. Maybe it was rejected specifically so that people could continue to use the feature in setuptools. The only difference I can discern is that one requires you to be using setuptools (and hence will work with zipped eggs, etc), while the other does not.

Comment: Quote from [PEP 382](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0382/): The current imperative approach to namespace packages has lead to multiple slightly-incompatible mechanisms for providing namespace packages. For example, pkgutil supports *.pkg files; setuptools doesn't. Likewise, setuptools supports inspecting zip files, and supports adding portions to its _namespace_packages variable, whereas pkgutil doesn't.

Comment: Shouldnt these two lines be put into both files: `Package-1/namespace/__init__.py` *and* `Package-2/namespace/__init__.py` providing that we don't know which Package dir is listed first?

Comment: Wondering the same of @Bula

Comment: @Bula: My own testing of this shows that it's only needed for the package that is listed first. But if you don't know, put them in both. At least I haven't had any troubles with doing it that way.

Comment: @ChristofferKarlsson yes that is the point, it is all right if you know which is first, but the real question is can you guarantee that it will be the first in any situation, i.e. for other users?

Comment: @Bula: You are correct. From [PEP 420](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/): "Every distribution needs to provide the same contents in its `__init__.py`, so that `extend_path` is invoked independent of which portion of the package gets imported first."

Comment: @MikeHordecki: Can you take a look at my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545177/namespace-package-with-both-tarball-and-egg-in-python

Comment: As another voice for `pkgutil` over `pkg_resources`: I've found that `pkg_resources` doesn't correctly respect `PYTHONPATH` order when you have two `__init__.py` files that both contain the `declare_namespace` call, but `pkgutil` does.

Comment: @joeforker on why `import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name)` is discouraged, [this might be a good read](https://github.com/ncoghlan/python-packaging-user-guide/blob/5b5c3b97f6a8871a5547c89c6962f105ea305403/source/namespace_packages.rst#pkg_resources-style-namespace-packages)

Comment: What is the example content of the module init module1/__init__.py?

Answer (score 5):

[This section should be pretty self-explanatory.](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#namespace-packages)

In short, put the namespace code in `__init__.py`, update `setup.py` to declare a namespace, and you are free to go.

Comment: You should always quote the relevant part of a link, in case the relevant link goes dead.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but someone recently commented on my blog that my posting about namespace packages was still relevant, so thought I would link to it here as it provides a practical example of how to make it go:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150425043954/http://cdent.tumblr.com/post/216241761/python-namespace-packages-for-tiddlyweb

That links to this article for the main guts of what's going on:

http://www.siafoo.net/article/77#multiple-distributions-one-virtual-package

The `__import__("pkg_resources").declare_namespace(__name__)` trick is pretty much drives the management of plugins in [TiddlyWeb](http://tiddlyweb.com/) and thus far seems to be working out.

Comment: The siafoo link is broken, here's a link to an archived copy:
https://web.archive.org/web/20200926015931/http://www.siafoo.net/article/77

Answer (score -11):

You have your Python namespace concepts back to front, it is not possible in python to put packages into modules. Packages contain modules not the other way around.

A Python package is simply a folder containing a `__init__.py` file. A module is any other file in a package (or directly on the `PYTHONPATH`) that has a `.py` extension. So in your example you have two packages but no modules defined. If you consider that a package is a file system folder and a module is file then you see why packages contain modules and not the other way around.

So in your example assuming Package-1 and Package-2 are folders on the file system that you have put on the Python path you can have the following:

```
Package-1/
  namespace/
  __init__.py
  module1.py
Package-2/
  namespace/
  __init__.py
  module2.py
```

You now have one package `namespace` with two modules `module1` and `module2`. and unless you have a good reason you should probably put the modules in the folder and have only that on the python path like below:

```
Package-1/
  namespace/
  __init__.py
  module1.py
  module2.py
```

Comment: I'm talking about things like `zope.x` where a bunch of related packages are released as separate downloads.

Comment: Ok, but what is the effect you are trying to achieve. If the folders containing related packages all on the PYTHONPATH the Python interpreter will find them for you with no extra effort on your part.

Comment: If you add both Package-1 and Package-2 to PYTHONPATH, only Package-1/namespace/ will be seen by Python.