# Deploy a sub package with distutils and pip

Tags: python, distutils, pip

I am wanting to create a suite of interrelated packages in Python. I would like them all to be under the same package but installable as separate components.

So, for example, installing the base package would provide the `mypackage` but there would be nothing in `mypackage.subpackage` until I install it separately.

Is this possible with distutils and pip?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a namespace package in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675734/how-do-i-create-a-namespace-package-in-python)

Comment: @plaes, `namespace` is only one of possible hacks. Is it possible to do this without namespaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "namespace packages", see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675734/how-do-i-create-a-namespace-package-in-python)