# Python full path import not working across branches in package tree

Tags: python, jython, jython-2.5

I have the following project structure:

```
Project
  - GUI
    - ...Modules
  - Data
    - Database
      - ...Modules
    - Files
      - ...Modules
  - Utilities
    - ...Modules
```

And I am trying to do some imports over package borders, for example:

in the file(Module) `Project.Database.dbdriver` I try to import `Project.Utilities.Conversions`. If I use a fully specified import like `import Project.Utilities.Conversions` this fails, it works with `import Utilities.Conversions`, i.e. I can not specify more off the path than those part that differ. However I would like to use fully specified paths, one reason beeing that pydev in eclipse likes them better (otherwise it shows me an error), the second reason is I find it confusing not to do so.

I have stumbled over this but think it is wrong/not needed here [How do I create a namespace package in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675734/how-do-i-create-a-namespace-package-in-python)

**Question:** how can I use fully specified includes when crossing subbranches in a package structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fully specified import failed because the current working directory of python(or jython) was set to Project. you can:

add the parent directory of Project to your python lib

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/parent/of/project')
```

or just change the working directory of jython to the parent of Project in the debug settings.(I don't know how to do it because I don't use pydev.)

Comment: the problem was not with pydev, but with the shell in which I ran the project. (outside eclipse). Thank you.

Comment: while your suggestion fixed my problem in the application I am developing for it created a problem within pydev, `import Project.GUI as gui` yields
`ImportError: No module named GUI`, and yes there is `__init__.py` and yes the projects parent folder shows up when I `print sys.path`, right before the error. But I will put that somewhere else sinc e you solved the initial question