# python import behaves oddly

Tags: python, jython, pydev, jython-2.5

I wanted to use full import names in my project (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047086)). The problem described there has been solved and everything works fine (**edit**: if the script is launched with `execfile`) outside eclipse and pydev (running on windows), in ccps on linux (which has jython built in). However eclipse gives me the following error:

```
from Project.gui import gui
ImportError: No module named gui
```

while my project structure inlcudes the following (everything without .py is a folder):

```
Project
    __init__.py
    gui
        __init__.py
        gui.py
    Project.py
```

I launch Project.Project.py and get the above error.
`print sys.path` right before the critical import yields:

```
['****\\Root\\Project', '****\\Root', 
 *bunch of jars/jython libs*,
'__classpath__', '__pyclasspath__/']
```

I am running eclipse and PyDev.

Comment: could you try renaming Project.py to something else and try again the import?

Comment: i just did, that is the solution, for some reason it ignores the package if it sees a module of that name... . Just for the hack of it: is there a way to make python actually search both if one fails?

Comment: "is there a way to make python search for both if one fails" -- Yes.  Read up on `try` and `except`.  It'll probably look something like:  `try: import Project; except ImporError: import Foo as Project`

Comment: Why are you giving modules the same names as their parent packages?

Comment: Because it is a convenice script, it is supposed to start a gui for the provided modules, and i thought this to be more convenient than index.py since I don't know of any standard for a main file, I know changed it to start which I don't like either

Comment: @ted -- Often the "main" file is named `core.py`, but I don't think there's any really established convention for this.  Also note that depending on what you've written into `__init__.py`, the user doesn't necessarily need to know the name of the "main" file.

Comment: @mgilson well I don't want init to start the gui since I want the user to bea bale to import the whole package for its functionality without starting the gui, thanks for the hint with `core.py`

Comment: @Eric: I know it has been a while, but I just noticed you touched up this question. Thank you, I always look for opportunities to improve my english, so keep those edits up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `\\Root\\Project` is first in your path, it will look inside the Project folder first so `from Project.gui` sees `Project.py`, but then throws an error because there's no gui.

You could temporarily put `sys.path.insert(0,"****\\Root")` in before the import just to check whether this is the case or not. But I'd take `****\\Root\\Project` out of your PYTHON_PATH.

then you could do

```
from Project import Project
```

and

```
from Project.gui import gui
```

Comment: well thanks for a correct solution, I will rename the file though as marius suggested since I consider this saver/easier