# Namespace packages and pip install -e

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I have a `ns.pkg2` package that depends on `ns.pkg1` package. I make a fork of it, publish it to git and want to install my version into my virtualenv. I use `pip install -e mygit` and end up with `ns.pkg` in `<env>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ns/pkg1` and `ns.pkg2` in `<env>/src/ns.pkg2` with an `<env>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ns.pkg2.egg-link`. Now I can import `ns` and `ns.pkg1` but not `ns.pkg2`. I couldn't find a way to install a package from git without `pip install -e` that calls `setup.py develop`. Also, I'm not sure it's not a problem with module code.

So, is it possible to co-install two modules from the same namespace from a tarball and directly from git?

Comment: what does the `__init__.py` of you `pkg2` look like? should be similar to what's described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675734/how-do-i-create-a-namespace-package-in-python)

Comment: @mata `pkg_resources.declare_namespace(__name__)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an open issue in `pip` related to `--editable` and namespace installations: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3

A [workaround was merged](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/541), and maybe you can solve your problem by doing:

```
$ pip install -e mygit --egg
```

Comment: you help me to solve really long term problem (I hope it is solved). Using `pip` I installed my namespaced package from pypi. And using buildout I worked on develop packages, sharing the same namespace. Sometime I got into problem with importing my develop based package, it was reported as missing. Solution for now? I **Install namespaced package from pypi using easy_install and not pip**. After this change, I am able to import my develop based one. Thank you for your link.