# Python: How to import sub-modules, from packages with the same name?

Tags: python, import, module

I have a project setup looks like this:

**Base project**

```
/some_disk/some_folder/
|-- project/
|   |-- package/
|   |   |-- src/
|   |   |   |-- file_a.py
|   |   |   |-- file_b.py
```

**Extension project**

```
/some_other_disk/some_folder/
|-- project/
|   |-- package/
|   |   |-- src/
|   |   |   |-- file_c.py
|   |   |   |-- file_d.py
```

Then I have a third project, in which I would like to be able to use both mopdules file_a and file_c.

In that third project, I have setup my Python path like this

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/some_disk/some_folder:/some_other_disk/some_folder
```

Then, to import the files, I have this in my main module:

```
import project.module.src.file_a
import project.module.src.file_c
```

This, however, only makes me able to import one of the modules, and having an *module not found* error on the other one.

Can I make this work using this project structure? Or will Python always only look into one of the "main"-modules and consider the sub-module not found if it's not in there?

EDIT: The project makes use of Python 2.6

Comment: Even if you can trick Python into letting you have 2 different packages with the exact same name, this sounds like a bad idea. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Basically, the main project is much bigger and contains a lots of data and has the project.module-layout, and the extension project is more like "plugin" project that, through the third project, can be used. Making the extension project a part of the main project isn't an option either. It has been added with symlinks in Unix before, but I want to get rid of them as they unintentionally might be added to the main project with the VCS-system.

Comment: @Wooble it's actually a common thing to want. The questioner wants **namespace packages**. And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675734/how-do-i-create-a-namespace-package-in-python) is a relevant question for that.

Comment: @Wessie: Thanks, that link helped me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a package file `__init__.py` in each of your `src` directories. They should contain the following two lines. See [this documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#module-pkgutil) for details. This solution works on Python 2.6 and is the canonical solution.

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! However, do I need to put it in both Base project and the Extended project?
A little testing showed that it seems like it's only needed for the project being first in the PYTHONPATH.

Comment: It is safest to put in both. That way you won't get bit if you wind up importing the Extended module before the Base module.

Answer (score 0):

This will make python search in your current directory/standard directories first, and for the second one, python will search in your pathtofile_c first before standard directories.

```
import project.module.src.file_a  #<--- here it searches some_disk first
sys.path.insert(0,'pathtofile_c') #<--- Changes your PYTHONPATH - inserts some_other_disk before standard directories
import project.module.src.file_c  #<--- here it searches some_other_disk first
```

This should clear python's confusion.

Answer (score -2):

You need to have **__init__.py** files within those directories to make python treat then as a package instead of plain directories.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) discussion to learn more about **init**.py files.

Note:I have edited my previous answer by removing the irrelevant content based on the discussion with the poster of the query.

Comment: I don't think that helps, as Python doesn't search both the import folders.
Just updated the original post, it's Python 2.6 that is used.

Comment: That's not the problem, I already have **__init__.py** files. The problem is that I have two packages with the same name.