# Will the first source in PYTHONPATH always be searched first?

Tags: python, pythonpath

Will the sources in PYTHONPATH always be searched in the very same order as they are listed? Or may the order of them change somewhere?

The specific case I'm wondering about is the view of PYTHONPATH before Python is started and if that differs to how Python actually uses it.

Comment: The relevance of this question [comes from this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675734/how-do-i-create-a-namespace-package-in-python). If the order is preserved or not affects the need of editing the **__init__.py** for one project or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually moderately complicated.  The story starts in the C code, which is what looks at `$PYTHONPATH` initially, but continues from there.

In all cases, but especially if Python is being invoked as an embedded interpreter (including "framework" stuff on MacOS X), at least a little bit of "magic" is done to build up an internal path string.  (When embedded, whatever is running the embedded Python interpreter can call `Py_SetPath`, otherwise python tries to figure out how it was invoked, then adjust and add `lib/pythonX.Y` where X and Y are the major and minor version numbers.)  This internal path construction is done so that Python can find its own standard modules, things like `collections` and `os` and `sys`.  `$PYTHONHOME` can also affect this process.  In general, though, the environment `$PYTHONPATH` variable—unless suppressed via `-E`—winds up in front of the semi-magic default path.

The whole schmear is used to set the initial value of `sys.path`.  But then as soon as Python starts up, it loads [`site.py`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) (unless suppressed via `-S`).  This modifies `sys.path` rather extensively—generally preserving things imported from `$PYTHONPATH`, in their original order, but shoving a lot of stuff (like system eggs) in front.<sup>1</sup>  Moreover, one of the things it does is load—if it exists—a per-user file `$HOME/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/sitepackages/usercustomize.py`, and *that* can do anything, there are no guarantees:

```
$ cat usercustomize.py
print 'hello from usercustomize'
$ python
hello from usercustomize
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 15 2013, 11:50:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 20070831 patched [FreeBSD]] on freebsd9
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

If I were to put:

```
import random, sys
random.shuffle(sys.path)
```

this would scramble `sys.path`, putting `$PYTHONPATH` elements in random order.  Arguably this is a case of "ok, you shot yourself in the foot, that's *your* problem". :-)  But anything I import can similarly mess with `sys.path`, so it's possible for something other than my own `usercustomize.py` to ruin the desired effect (of `$PYTHONPATH` ordering being preserved).

---

<sup>1</sup> Footnote (late edit): actually the eggs come from `site-packages/site.py`, which does its own `os.getenv("PYTHONPATH")`.  So it's even messier, in a way.  The general principle applies though: standard code *should* preserve path order, but you can break it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, very well described of how things work :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be searched *always* in the same order as paths are listed in `PYTHONPATH`, but you can do 

`import sys

sys.path.insert(0, 'path/to/your/module')`
It will add your module to the first place in `PYTHONPATH`
check this out http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Answer (score 0):

PYTHONPATH passed to sys.path there any module can modify it before importing another modules.