# Re-opening a package in Python

Tags: python

Maybe it's not possible (I'm more used to Ruby, where this sort of thing is fine). I'm writing a library that provides additional functionality to docker-py, which provides the `docker` package, so you just `import docker` and then you get access to `docker.Client` etc.

Because it seemed a logical naming scheme, I wanted users to pull in my project with `import docker.mymodule`, so I've created a directory called `docker` with an `__init__.py`, and `mymodule.py` inside it.

When I try to access `docker.Client`, Python can't see it, as if my `docker` package has hidden it:

```
import docker
import docker.mymodule

docker.Client() # AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Client'
```

Is this possible, or do all top-level package names have to differ between source trees?

Comment: You could only do that if `docker` was set up as a namespace package, which it isn't. See [`zope.schema`](https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.schema/blob/master/setup.py#L93), [`zope.interface`](https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.interface/blob/master/setup.py#L93), etc. for an example of a namespace package (`zope` is the namespace package here).

Comment: @LukasGraf thank you! If you post that as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: See [How do I create a namespace package in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675734/how-do-i-create-a-namespace-package-in-python). Also note that since python3.3 there is [built-in support for namespace packages](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-420-implicit-namespace-packages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would only be possible if `docker` was set up as a [namespace package](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#namespace-packages) (which [it isn't](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker-py/blob/master/setup.py)).

See [`zope.schema`](https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.schema/blob/master/setup.py#L93), [`zope.interface`](https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.interface/blob/master/setup.py#L93), etc. for an example of a namespace package (`zope` is the namespace package here). Because `zope` is declared as a namespace package in `setup.py`, it means that `zope` doesn't refer to a particular module or directory on the file system, but is a namespace shared by several packages. This also means that the result of `import zope` is pretty much undefined - it will simply import the top-level module of the first `zope.*` package found in the import path.

Therefore, when dealing with namespace packages, you need to explicitely import a specific one with `import zope.schema` or `from zope import schema`.

Unfortunately, namespace packages aren't that well documented. As noted by `@Bakuriu` in the comment, these are some resources that contain some helpful information:

- [Stackoverflow: How do I create a namespace package in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675734/how-do-i-create-a-namespace-package-in-python)
- [Built-in support for namespace packages in Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-420-implicit-namespace-packages)
- [Namespace packages in the setuptools documentation](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#namespace-packages)
- [Post about namespace packages at sourceweaver.com](http://www.sourceweaver.com/musings/posts/python-namespace-packages)