# Namespace package with both tarball and egg in Python

Tags: python, package, pip, egg

I've followed [this tutorial](http://cdent.tumblr.com/post/216241761/python-namespace-packages-for-tiddlyweb) to make a package with namespace. Then I use `pip install xxx.tar.gz` to install and everything works like expect.

The problem is that my environment has already a lots of packages with the same namespace and installed with `easy_install` and `eggs`, and python can not find the old packages anymore. I understand that if I create tar.gz instead of eggs for all the olds pacakges, it would work fine but this is a lots of time to spend.

How can I make the new and old packages work together with two different installation methods ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem (I think). It appears that this is a [well known problem](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3). The solution given to me was to just use pip for everything. I was specifically using `python setup.py install` alongside `pip install w/e` and it wasn't working, I'm guessing yours is roughly the same problem.