# Namespace package conflict

Tags: python, virtualenv, namespace-package

I have a package that I'm working on ([LDB_Algebra](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/LDB_Algebra)). It has an extra that depends on another package that I created ([LDB_LAPACK](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/LDB_LAPACK/0.1)). I have created a virtualenv and installed each of these packages as shown:

```
$ virtualenv -p pypy ve_pypy
$ . ve_pypy/bin/activate
(ve_pypy) $ pip install LDB_LAPACK
...
(ve_pypy) $ python setup.py install
... (Installs LDB_Algebra)
```

Each has the following for its `__init__.py` file under the ldb package:

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

**Problem:**

The trouble is that when I try to use `ldb.algebra` it reports that it can't find the package. Just to make sure it hasn't completely lost everything I attempt to import `ldb.lapack` and that works fine. This suggests to me that I'm having a namespace package problem. It seems a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545177/namespace-package-with-both-tarball-and-egg-in-python) (with no answer sadly). Upon investigating the directory structure of my virtualenv I find that under `ve_pypy/site-packages/` there is a folder for the `ldb` namespace package which includes the `lapack` package but not the `algebra` package. I also see an egg file, `LDB_Algebra-0.3.2-py2.7.egg`. Inside this egg file in the `ldb` directory is an `__init__.py` file with the appropriate namespace declaration (as above). Presumably this is supposed to be where it gets the `ldb.algebra` package from but it's not looking there.

**Questions:**

1. Can anyone confirm with a reference that what I'm seeing is a known issue (i.e. that I'm not just doing some slightly wrong that's causing all these troubles)? Are eggs and w/e the pip install method created (the `ldb` package directory under `site-packages`) fundamentally incompatible?
2. Assuming that the answer to the first question is that my method of package installing is fundamentally flawed, is there an easier way of installing the `LDB_LAPACK` package from pypi and the `LDB_Algebra` package from my local directory? I'm not a setuptools wiz or anything so the answer may be very straightforward (don't overlook the obvious).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a [well known problem](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3). The solution that was suggested to me and seems to work fine is to use `pip install .` instead of `python setup.py install`.