# Standard directory for installed Python package's data

Tags: python

I'm working on a package that uses data from external git repository. When it's doing its job, it first cloning git repository and then copies files from it to some other location.

Where should I save this repository (and other non-python files) in my filesystem? Is there any standard place for that?

Sure, I could just use `site-packages/` directory for my files. But the problem is, git repository could contain python packages too, and I don't want them to be importable.

Is there, maybe, some way to specifically exclude some folder from `site-packages/`? I think `*.dist-info` folders are excluded, should I create a fake one for my package?

Thank you very much.

Comment: First, I can't be sure that it will be existed on the system. But in case I don't know smth, I still want that files to survive reboot, so `/tmp` isn't quite a case.

Comment: `/tmp` will exist on all GNU/Linux systems. What is the OS you use?

Comment: If possible, I wanted it to be inside virtualenv directory. Or is it non-common practice? I don't really have much experience with that sort of things. Is it ok to use smth like $HOME for package-specific files? For me, it looks like unnecessary polluting the system.

Comment: I'm using Debian, and yes, /tmp is there. What about Windows?

Comment: I'd say be bold, pick somewhere, and then let users override the default location either with an argument or environment variable

Comment: Feels bad, but acceptable. Looks like pip using `~/.cache/pip` for caches. I guess I'm just overthinking a problem here.
It would be nice, though, to have standard directory for package-specific files inside `virtualenv/` root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install them into a subdirectory of your package directory in `site-packages`. If the subdirectory doesn't have an `__init__.py` file or if it's name has a dash (-) or other character that isn't valid in a Python identifier it can't be imported using the `import` statement nor can any Python file located under it.

So for example, if your package name is `mypackage`, you could use `site-packages/mypackage/data-files` as the location to store your data.

Comment: This is why `.dist-info` files are not importable, not because of some weird exclusion somewhere, right?

Comment: It looks like omitting `__init__.py` on the top-level doesn't solve a problem, because when you're doing that, Python 3 thinks that it's a [namespace package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675734/how-do-i-create-a-namespace-package-in-python/27586272#27586272).
Also, I kind of can't be sure that my folder won't have `__init__.py` file on top-level anyway.

Although, adding `-` as a part of top-level directory is a perfectly valid and nice way to solve the problem.

Comment: If my remarks are valid, please remove the part about `__init__.py` from the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @mkurnikov I didn't suggest omitting `__init__.py` from the "top level". I suggested omitting from the subdirectory of your package directory. Your package directory (`site-packages/mypackage` in my example) must have an `__init__.py` file otherwise it's not a package. Any subdirectories of the package directory (eg. `site-packages/mypackage/datafiles`) can't become namespace packages. Only directories in `sys.path` are searched (eg. `site-packages`), not any of their subdirectories. Only direct subdirectories found in the directories in `sys.path` can become namespace packages.

Comment: Yes, that definitely makes sense. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Keeping non-python source code files in package directory still feels kind of ugly, but I guess it's my own problems. 
I'm accepting the answer and lets close it here. Thank you.