# Use cases for __init__.py in python 3.3+

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

Now that `__init__.py` is [no longer required](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-420-implicit-namespace-packages) to make a directory recognized as a package, is it best practice to avoid them entirely if possible? Or are there still well-accepted use cases for `__init__.py` in python 3.3+?

From what I understand, `__init__.py` were very commonly used to run code at module import time ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29509611/336527) to encapsulate internal file structure of the package or to perform some initialization steps). Are these use cases still relevant with python 3.3+?

Comment: The only real reason I see, to keep using `__init__.py`, is for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @leaf so what about the [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29509611/336527) I mentioned? What's a canonical way to do this in python 3.3+?

Answer (score 6):

There's a very good discussion of this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675734/how-do-i-create-a-namespace-package-in-python#answer-27586272), and you should probably be familiar with [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) to clarify the difference between and *regular packages* (use `__init__.py`) and *namespace packages* (don't).

What I offer by way of answer is a combination of reading, references, and opinion. No claims to being "canonical" or "pythonic" here.

> Are [initialization] use cases still relevant with python 3.3+?

**Yes**. Take your [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29509611/336527) as a use case, where the package author wants to bring several things into the root package namespace so the user doesn't have to concern themselves with its internal structure.

Another case is creating a [hierarchy](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch10.html#_making_a_hierarchical_package_of_modules) of modules. That reference (O'Reilly) actually says:

> The purpose of the `__init__.py` files is to include optional initialization code that runs as different levels of a package are encountered.

They do consider namespace packages in that discussion, but continue:

> All things being equal, include the `__init__.py` files if you’re just starting out with the creation of a new package.

So, for your second question,

> is it best practice to avoid `__init__.py` entirely if possible?

**No**, unless your intent is to create a *namespace* package rather than a regular package, in which case you **must not** use `__init__.py`.

Why might you want that? The O'Reilly reference has the clearest [example](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch10.html#namespacepackage) I've seen about why namespace packages are cool, which is being able to *collapse* namespaces from separate, independently-maintained packages:

```
foo-package/
    spam/
        blah.py

bar-package/
    spam/
        grok.py
```

Which allows

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.extend(['foo-package', 'bar-package'])
>>> import spam.blah
>>> import spam.grok
>>>
```

So anyone can extend the namespace with their own code. Cool.

Comment: Then, perhaps, it is best practice to avoid _packages_ whenever possible, and use _namespaces_ instead? Or is there some problem with that approach?

Comment: It seems the advantage of namespace is that they are extensible. Their disadvantage is that you can't have `__init__.py` in them and therefore can't do some things (like encapsulating the file structure, performing initialization, etc.). Does it sound right?