# How to import two python files as a single module in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance

Im working in a Python project with several functionalities. Each of these functionalities works as its own project with its own modules.

I have defined an **utils_general.py** module with general functions that can be used by each functionality. In addition, each functionality has its own **utils_functionality_x.py** module with functions that will be used only in that module. The structure of my project is as follows:

```
.
+-- __init__.py
+-- src
|   +-- utils_general.py
|   +-- functionality_1.py
|   |   +-- __init__.py
|   |   +-- main_functionality_1.py
|   |   +-- utils_functionality_1.py
|   +-- functionality_2.py
|   |   +-- __init__.py
|   |   +-- main_functionality_2.py
|   |   +-- utils_functionality_2.py
+-- .gitignore
+-- README.md
```

In the above example, in **main_functionality_1.py** it will be used functions from **utils_general.py** and from **utils_functionality_1.py**. As well, in **main_functionality_2.py** it will be used functions from **utils_general.py** and from **utils_functionality_2.py**.

I would like to import all the functions of the utils' files as if it was a single module. With this I mean, I would like to make **utils_functionality_1.py** "inherit" the functions of **utils_general.py**. The idea is something similar to class-inheritance, but the two files are completelly functional (in **utils_general.py** and **utils_functionality_1.py** there are no classes defined, only functions).

For example, this will result that in **main_functionality_1.py** I could access to the functions of **utils_general.py** and **utils_functionality_1.py** with the name `utils` (notice that no functions have the same name in **utils_general.py** and **utils_functionality_1.py**). For example, I would like to do something like this (this won't work):

```py
# This is pseudo-code and won't work
import src.utils_general as utils
import src.functionality_1.utils_functionality_1 as utils
```

All I can think of is importing the functions of **utils_general.py** into **utils_functionality_1.py** and then creating a wrapper function that can be called from outside. Something like this:

*Code in **utils_functionality_1.py**:*

```py
# Code in utils_functionality_1.py
import src.utils_general as utils_general

def function_general(*args, **kwargs):
    return utils_general.function_general(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is there a better way/good-practice to do this "pseudo-inheritance" between modules in Python?

Comment: You can do  'from package_name.src.utils_general import * ' in utils_functionality_1 if your main_functionality_1 is being called from the package and can resolve the import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import all the names from `utils_general` in `utils_functionality_1` and that's it.

```
# utils_functionality_1.py
from utils_general import *
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to change your folder structure a bit, but you might be able to use ["namespace packages"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) to extend an existing module with additional files.

> Namespace packages are a mechanism for splitting a single Python package across multiple directories on disk.

[Here's and answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137114/use-cases-for-init-py-in-python-3-3/40249230#40249230) on the topic.