# how to import a directory as python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

if there is a directory `/home/project/aaa`.
and I know that it is a Python package.

so, how can i import this module by just knowing its path.

means that, i hope that code is worked:

```
aaa = load_module("/home/project/aaa")
```

the only way i knew is that, adding `/home/project` to `sys.path`

but it maybe incur some problem:

if i add `/home/project` to `sys.path`

and if there a dir `pytest` in path `/home/project`.

then the official pytest package would not work.

i try `importlib` yet.
but it seems that `importlib` can just import a file as a module, not a path.

so, i try it:

```
aaa = importlib.import_module("aaa", "/home/project")
```

or

```
aaa = importlib.import_module("aaa", "/home/project/aaa")
```

both of them are not work.

so, is there any other way to do what i want?

oh, i am using Python3.6

---

UPDATED AT 20170628

**(NOTICE: there is a `__init__.py` in folder `/home/project/aaa`)**

all solutions i known is that import module from a single file.

if there is `bbb.py` file in folder `/home/project/aaa`

then, add `/home/project/aaa` to  `sys.path` or `__path__` (whatever)

`import bbb` is worked, but not the `import aaa`

what i wanna ask is how to import **folder (or directory)** as a module.

for my example, folder `aaa` is consided as a module.

i wanna use `import aaa` not `import {SOMETHING IN AAA}`

Comment: LMGTFY: https://askubuntu.com/questions/470982/how-to-add-a-python-module-to-syspath/471168

Comment: @EgorBiriukov: The questioner already knows how to add a directory to `sys.path`, and they have given a good reason to want a different option.

Answer (score 15):

Here are five different ways of how to accomplish that task.

For the following considerations I refer to Python 3.5+.

---

## Register a custom [`Finder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder)

Python uses [finders](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-finder) for when importing modules. If a finder knows how to deal with a particular requested module then it returns a corresponding [module spec](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-module-spec) and otherwise `None`. Python has three different finders already registered which can be found in `sys.meta_path`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.meta_path
[<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>, <class '_frozen_importlib_external.PathFinder'>]
```

The first one handles built-in modules, the second one frozen modules (some kind of "self-contained" Python scripts, see [the wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze)) and the last one handles everything which can be found on `sys.path`. So if we modified `sys.path` by appending `'/home/project'` then it would be this finder which provides the corresponding spec.

Instead of modifying `sys.path` we can register our own finder which uses the functionality of [`PathFinder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.PathFinder):

```
import importlib.machinery

class CustomFinder(importlib.machinery.PathFinder):
    _path = ['/home/project']

    @classmethod
    def find_spec(cls, fullname, path=None, target=None):
        return super().find_spec(fullname, cls._path, target)
```

Here we explicitly tell the `PathFinder` to look into the `/home/project` when importing modules.

We can register the finder as follows:

```
import sys
sys.meta_path.append(CustomFinder)
```

Then we can import the package `aaa` which will be found by the `CustomFinder`:

```
import aaa
```

For more information see [PEP-302](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/).

## Extend `sys.path`

We can modify `sys.path` in order to put the required package on the path:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/project')
import aaa
from aaa import whatever
# Optionally remove the added path.
sys.path.pop()
```

Appending this directory to the path won't block "existing" (e.g. built-in packages) with the same name due to the [order of searching](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#searching) that is performed during an import.

## Add a local module containing a `__path__`

You can add a local module `aaa.py` (in fact you can add it to any location which is on the Python path) which contains the following code:

```
__path__ = ['/home/project/aaa']
```

Then you can perform `import` statements which will refer to the package that you referred to with the `__path__` variable:

```
from aaa import whatever
```

If you want to `import aaa` you can mimic this by applying the same method one level up in the directory hierarchy. Add a local module `project.py` (for example) with the following code:

```
__path__ = ['/home/project']
```

Then you can do

```
from project import aaa
```

which is very much similar `import aaa` if `aaa` was on the path (provided that no other module named `project` has precedence on the path).

## Create a symlink pointing to the package

You can create a symlink that points to the package's directory. For example on Unix:

```
ln -s /home/project/aaa aaa
```

Then you can import the package via `import aaa`, given you're executing this in the directory where you placed the symlink.

The symlink can also be created within your program via

```
import os

package = '/home/project/aaa'
target = os.path.split(package)[-1]  # For example.
if not os.path.exists(target):
    # `target_is_directory=True` is needed for Windows platform.
    os.symlink(package, target, target_is_directory=True)

# Now import the package.
aaa = __import__(target)
```

## Install the package via [`setuptools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)

You can add a `/home/project/setup.py` script which contains (for example) the following code:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='aaa',
    packages=[
        'aaa',
        # Add any sub-packages that `aaa` contains here.
    ]
)
```

Then you can install the package via `cd /home && pip install -e project` and you can readily import it in your other Python files:

```
import aaa
from aaa import whatever
```

By using [`virtualenv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) you can keep your installed packages in a clean state.

Comment: `/home/project/aaa` is a directory, not a single file.

Comment: @KilerdChan I updated my answer in order to clarify. All three methods work for your scenario (`aaa` being a directory). Modifying `sys.path` is probably the simplest one. I consider installing the package via `setuptools` & `pip` the cleanest method. You mentioned in your question that you are worried about modifying `sys.path` shadowing existing (e.g. built-in packages) but it won't due to the [search order](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#searching) during an import. If you _append_ to `sys.path` then the added location has the least priority.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I'm trying to figure out how to edit a project I cloned from github, and this was the missing piece!

Comment: @a_guest, Thank you! This is wonderfully complete and detailed. :)  

Regarding the 3rd option (*Add a local module containing a\ __path\__*), does the 2nd half of that approach (beginning with "If you want to import aaa you can mimic...") depend upon the `aaa` directory containing a `__init__.py` file?

Comment: @dbanas If you want to mimic `import aaa` via `from project import aaa` then `aaa` can be really anything: 1) it can be module `aaa.py` 2) it can be a directory containing an `__init__.py` 3) it can be a directory without `__init__.py`. For case 1) and 2) `aaa` will be loaded as a module and for case 3) it will be loaded as a [namespace package](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27586272/3767239)).