# Python: TypeError shows up during CI/CD process

Tags: python-3.x, git, continuous-integration, package, pytest

I tried to add a TXT file into my python package, load it by `pkg_resources`, and do some other stuff with data after that. The structure of my python package is following:

```
package_name
  |-- requirements.txt
  |-- setup.py
  |-- MANIFEST.in
  |-- package
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- name
      |-- __init__.py
      |-- my_file.py
      |-- test
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- test_1.py
      |-- data
        |-- MY_DATA.txt
```

The content of `~/package_name/package/name/my_file.py`:

```
import pkg_resources

DATA_PATH = 'package.name.data'
MY_DATA_PATH = pkg_resources.resource_filename(DATA_PATH, 'MY_DATA.txt')


def do_some_stuff_with_data(data_path=MY_DATA_PATH):
    ...
```

When I run tests on my local machine, the code runs without any problem. However, when I try to push it into `git` repository via CI/CD, tests fail on the error below:

```
/tmp/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/package/name/test/test_name.py:13: in <module>
    from package.name.my_file import (
/tmp/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/package/name/my_file.py:28: in <module>
    MY_DATA_PATH = pkg_resources.resource_filename(DATA_PATH, 'MY_DATA.txt')
/tmp/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:1206: in resource_filename
    return get_provider(package_or_requirement).get_resource_filename(
/tmp/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:437: in get_provider
    return _find_adapter(_provider_factories, loader)(module)
/tmp/testenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:1452: in __init__
    self.module_path = os.path.dirname(getattr(module, '__file__', ''))
/tmp/testenv/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py:156: in dirname
    p = os.fspath(p)
E   TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

I know, that data path is written correctly. I checked the typos for several times. I also thought that the error could have been caused by not adding data path to `MANIFEST.in` file. However, the addition did not solve the problem.

Do you have any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Namespace packages are permitted to have their `__file__` set to `None`: see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/1675734/1256452. (I'm not sure how useful this is here since in Python 3.7 everything is supposed to "just work", but that's why this is a comment, not an answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is anyone with the same problem, I have solved the issue by adding an `__init__.py` file into `~/package_name/package/name/data/` folder.

Comment: Thank you from the bottom of my heart.  I have no idea how you worked that one out, but great job.  For anyone who comes after me, I needed only an empty `__init__.py` file in my `package` directory.