# Subdirectory structure breaks C++ extension build

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, python-c-api

I can't seem to get around a problem where importing a C++ extension module no longer works when a subdirectory structure is used.

The two cases below present a simple working case and a slightly altered case that I cannot for the life of me get to work.

#### Scenario 1 (working)

Project tree:

```
demo_cext/         # Current working directory for all of this
├── _cmodule.cc
└── setup.py
```

Contents of `setup.py`:

```py
import setuptools

module = setuptools.Extension("_cmod", sources=["_cmodule.cc"], language="c++")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setuptools.setup(name="cmod", ext_modules=[module])
```

Contents of `_cmodule.cc`, basically the hello world of C extensions, which creates a function `foo()` that takes no args and returns 5.

```cpp
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *
foo(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    /* noargs() */
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "")) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return PyLong_FromLong(5);
}

static PyMethodDef FooMethods[] = {
    {"foo",  foo,      METH_VARARGS,  "Do the foo"},
    {NULL,   NULL,     0,             NULL}
};

PyDoc_STRVAR(module_doc, "This is the module docstring.");
static struct PyModuleDef cmodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "cmod",
    module_doc,
    -1,
    FooMethods,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit__cmod(void) {
    PyObject* m = PyModule_Create(&cmodule);
    if (m == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return m;
}
```

The whole thing works like a charm:

```sh
$ python3 -V
Python 3.7.4
$ python3 setup.py build install
```

```py
>>> import _cmod
>>> _cmod.foo()
5
```

#### Scenario 2 (broken)

Reorienting the project a bit to a layout covered specifically in [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#extension-names-and-packages).

```sh
$ rm -rf build/ dist/ cmod.egg-info/ && \
> mkdir cmod/ && touch cmod/__init__.py && \
> mv _cmodule.cc cmod/
```

Leaves me with:

```
demo_cext/         # Current working directory for all of this
├── cmod
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── _cmodule.cc
└── setup.py
```

I change `setup.py` slightly:

```py
import setuptools

module = setuptools.Extension("cmod._cmod", sources=["cmod/_cmodule.cc"], language="c++")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setuptools.setup(name="cmod", ext_modules=[module])
```

Now after again running:

```sh
$ python3 setup.py build install
```

Trying to import the module leaves me with:

```py
>>> from cmod import _cmod
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name '_cmod' from 'cmod' (.../demo_cext/cmod/__init__.py)
>>> import cmod._cmod
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmod._cmod'
```

**What do I have wrong here?  I'm sure it is something simple with naming conventions.**  This seems to fly directly in the face of [how this is all laid out in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#extension-names-and-packages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing directories before launching Python (e.g. `cd ..`). Your traceback indicates that you're finding `cmod` in `demo_cext/cmod` (your source directory, not the installation directory), but the built extension wouldn't be there (it would be somewhere in `demo_cext/build` after `build`, and your system site-packages directory after `install`).

An alternative solution, if this will only ever be used on Python 3, would be to get rid of the `cmod/__init__.py` file; an empty `__init__.py` file isn't necessary to make a package in Python 3 thanks to [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/). By removing the `__init__.py`, implicit namespace packaging should take over, and it should automatically search *all* `cmod` packages in `sys.path` for the submodule you're trying to import.

Comment: @BradSolomon: Then implicit namespace packages won't work. But for actual users of your package, they won't be running from a with a working directory with `cmod/__init__.py`, so the first solution (`cd`ing out of your development directory to test the installed module) would accurately reproduce your user's experience. The alternative solution is mostly a convenience for you, the developer, by letting Python search *both* the source directory *and* the installed package to find `_cmod`, without needing to bypass searching the source directory by changing the working directory.

Comment: @BradSolomon: The problem isn't your shell's `PATH`, it's `sys.path` in Python (where Python looks for modules; the hacky `PYTHONPATH` environment variable can change it, not `PATH`). `sys.path` is implicitly prefixed with the current working directory, so launching from `.../demo_cext`, it will find `.../demo_cext/cmod` before it even looks in the installed packages. If you want to make it work w/o changing directories while still doing custom stuff in `__init__.py`, you could [make your `__init__.py` *explicitly* behave as a namespace package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27586272/364696).

Comment: @BradSolomon: Nope, the Python files are fine, because they're the same in the source `cmod` and the globally installed `cmod`. It's only extensions that have the problem, because they're just raw C source files in the source `cmod`, and actual extension modules only in the globally installed `cmod`. Making an explicit namespace module should still work just fine; the answer I linked has the behavior of expanding the number of places it will look for sub-packages/modules of `cmod` (so it'll still check source `cmod` first, then check installed `cmod` if it's not found).

Comment: I was able to fully verify pretty much all that you pointed out here by creating a simple PyPI package: https://pypi.org/project/hello-c-extension/.  It pip installs without a hitch and allows access to both the Python and C modules.  So, as you point out, the difficulty appears to be in local development specifically when the developer is sitting in the project root.